# Is $\mathcal{L}(V)^*$ path connected?

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras, path-connected

Assume that $V$ is a complex Banach space, $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is the Banach algebra composed of bounded linear operators with the norm  $\lVert A\rVert=\sup\{\lVert Av\rVert:\lVert v\rVert\leq 1 \}$.

$$ \mathcal{L}(V)^* :=\{A\in \mathcal{L}(V):\text{$A$ is invertible in $\mathcal{L}(V)$} \}.$$

Here, I wonder if $\mathcal{L}(V)^*$ is path-connected?

In fact, when $V=\mathbb{C}^n$, $\mathcal{L}(V)^*=GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is path conneced. So how about a more general situation?

Comment: At least $\mathcal{L}(V)^*$ is path-connected when $V$ is a complex Hilbert space. However, the proof that I know relies critically on the Hilbert space structure of $V$, and so, I am not sure if this is still true for general $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The question has been edited and this answer is no longer valid.

For any normed linear space of dimension a least $2$,  $X$ $\{x\in X: x \neq 0\}$ is path connected.  In fact, given $x,y \neq 0$ we can find a path within the the two dimensional space spanned by $x$ and $y$ which connects $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean should be $\{ x\in X: \exist x^{-1}\in X\}$, my desciption is wrong. I will edit this quesion later.

Comment: @C.J.Du Please don't edit questions in such a way that it makes an answer invalid. If it turns out you didn't ask what you wanted to ask, please write a new question.